# Kafka - org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Failed to configure SaslClientAuthenticator after Kafka restart

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I connect my app to Kafka through SASL_SSL using keytab. At first it worked well with consumer, but once it got an error after Kafka restart.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Failed to configure SaslClientAuthenticator
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Principal could not be determined from Subject, this may be a transient failure due to Kerberos re-login
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.firstPrincipal(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:632) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.<init>(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:202) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildClientAuthenticator(SaslChannelBuilder.java:286) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.lambda$buildChannel$1(SaslChannelBuilder.java:228) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.<init>(KafkaChannel.java:143) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildChannel(SaslChannelBuilder.java:236) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.buildAndAttachKafkaChannel(Selector.java:338) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.registerChannel(Selector.java:329) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:256) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:992) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.access$600(NetworkClient.java:73) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:1163) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:1051) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:558) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:280) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:251) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:242) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.awaitMetadataUpdate(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:164) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:277) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:240) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.coordinatorUnknownAndUnreadySync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:492) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:524) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1276) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1240) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1220) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1726) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1701) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1502) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1394) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[?:?]
```

How to fix this and avoid such errors in future?

Comment: I have only one way to restart my application. After booting it works normally